# Elements in object passed as props in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing an object as props to a component.

Debugging if I console the object I see it and its properties.  However when I try to access one of the properties, I get undefined.  See the code sample and then the console output.

```
console.info("OBJ");
console.info(this.props.settings);
console.info("OBJ VALUE: " + this.props.settings.showApptsShows);
```

[image]

Comment: `showApptsShows` vs `showApptsShow`

Comment: If any of our answers helped you, please checkmark the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. you are trying to access `showApptsShows`

The property is `showApptsShow`. Note there is no trailing `s`

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo:

```
console.info("OBJ VALUE: " + this.props.settings.showApptsShows);
```

has an extra 's' at the end.